# How to display a "waiting page" while a CGI is running?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have a cgi script that takes long time (30 sec) to generate the results before printing out the html. I want to show an intermediary page that says "Loading, please wait..." with an animated GIF before displaying the results.
Thanks

Comment: So you should have a look at JavaScript ('Ajax').

Comment: You should totaly drop whatever you are doing and use jQuery (tm) :)

Answer (score 4):

Fork the process and keep a reference to it in a session. Then poll the script periodically for a status update.

There is a [more detailed explanation](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html) with code examples that was originally published in Linux Magazine. Perl Monks has [further discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=596850).

You could use JavaScript (and XMLHttpRequest) to do your polling instead of reloading the whole page (do remember to [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) though).

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution: Make static html page, with your loading text and gif, and with an JS script loading your CGI script with [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHR). It is very simple with libs like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its ajax helper functions like [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys for the help, this what I did:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ray={
ajax:function(st)
    {
        this.show('load');
    },
show:function(el)
    {
        this.getID(el).style.display='';
    },
getID:function(el)
    {
        return document.getElementById(el);
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#load{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
border:3px double #999;
background:#f7f7f7;
width:300px;
height:300px;
margin-top:-150px;
margin-left:-150px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
text-align:center;
line-height:300px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial,tahoma;
font-size:18pt;
}
</style>
<div id="load" style="display:none;">Loading... Please wait<br/><img src="images/loading.gif"></div>
<form action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi" method="get" onsubmit="return ray.ajax()">
<input type="text" value="Test" name="q">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```