# html + perl : how display a waiting page/popup while user submit a form

Tags: html, forms, perl

I have a html form that calls a perl script as an action in which I saved data in the DB. 
I would like a wait screen to appear while this script is being called. How could I do?

Comment: What are you using? Old school CGI with Apache?

Comment: yes, in my html I have a form like: ''' <form action="/cgi-bin/insert_user.pl" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">''' and in the script insert_user.pl I actually save the data on the DB and redirect the user to another page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7632717/1030675

Answer (score 0):

// jQuery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function(){
        // show image here
        $("#busy").show();
    },
    complete:function(){
        // hide image here
        $("#busy").hide();
    }
});
```